# iOS: Login with Google

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-signin

I am trying to login with Google. It's working for all accounts. But behaviour is different. For some accounts it sending full public profile i.e DisplayName, Gender, Email address, User ID etc.

For some (new) accounts it's just sending email address and user ID DisplayName and Gender is nil. I need all these parameters every time when login with Google.  Why these parameters are missing for some accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)

When Google Sign in process complete then put this code

```
-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
    {
        if (error)
        {
            // Do some error handling here.
        }
        else
        {
            GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];
            query.fields = @"id,emails,image,name,displayName";
            GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
            plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
            [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];
            plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";
            [plusService executeQuery:query  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPerson *person, NSError *error)
            {
                if (!error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Display name : %@",[person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", person.name.familyName]);
                    NSLog(@"email id : %@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
```

I hope your useful this link and code.